# XML to XSD,no name space bound error

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

My xml is this,and i have written xsd also.The correct way of namespace? its giving error.
**prefix not bound**It has something to take with the name space

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<Authorization xmlns="www.abc.com/AB_2012_09_14.xsd">

        <CVCCodeSwitch /> 
       </Authorization>
```

And the XSD i have written is giving error that the "xs" prefix is not bound.

XSD for referrence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<xs:schema xlmns:xs="www.abc.com/AB_2012_09_14" elementFormDefault="qualified">

            <xs:element name="CVCCodeSwitch" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:decimal"/>
    <xs:element name="TransactionDate">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `xmlns` attribute is not spelled correctly (you wrote `xlmns`), so the parser complains that the `xs` prefix is not bound.

If you fix that you will have another error because you can't bind the `schema` elements to your namespace. You have to bind them to the XML Schema namespace:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ... >
```

To qualify your types, you need to declare your namespace as the `targetNamespace` and default `xmlns` namespace of your schema (it has to be identical to the namespace in your instance):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="www.abc.com/AB_2012_09_14.xsd"
           targetNamespace="www.abc.com/AB_2012_09_14.xsd"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"> ...
```

Finally, your instance will not be valid because the `CVCCodeSwitch` element, according to the schema, cannot be empty (it must contain an integer). It will validate if you change it to:

```
<CVCCodeSwitch>0</CVCCodeSwitch>
```

Comment: >>It was of great help. the last point you mentioned. Acutually I have my xml file and I am writing my XSD.So could you please tell me how should i define that element in my xsd? I am not sure that element will have integer value or string. If it is defined like this

<CVCCodeSwitch /> 

What should i write in my xsd so that it gets validated without any errors.

Comment: You can define it as `xs:string`. The null value is not a valid `xs:integer`. You could use the `nillable="true"` attribute but it would require that you change the instance as well (you would need to add an `xsi:nil="true"` attribute to `<CVCCodeSwitch/>`. But if you use: `<xs:element name="CVCCodeSwitch" type="xs:string"/>` it will validate.

Comment: @ helderdarocha If I use below line will it validate: `<xs:element name="CVCCodeSwitch" type="xs:integer" xs:nillable="true"/>` Or >>>> `<xs:element name="CVCCodeSwitch" type="xs:string" xs:nillable="true"/>`

Comment: The second one (without the xs:). An empty string is still a valid xs:string. An empty integer is not a valid `xs:integer`. It's not sufficient to add `nillable="true"` to the integer declaration (you will have to add `xsi:nil="true"` to the original XML as well. But if you use `xs:string` you will have no problem (and don't need the `nillable` attribute)